# what is meant be "Anonymous Authentication" enabled and edit it to specific user

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-authentication

iis 7.5 , for a site  "Anonymous Authentication" can be 'enabled' and can be 'edited' it to a specific user.What does it mean. Enabling 'Anonymous' means allowing all the users, then what is meant for 'edit' it and add a specific user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default anonymous users use IUSR account when connecting to the site. You can change this user to a different user (who might have different privileges) and all anonymous users will use that account when connecting to the site, instead of the default IUSR account.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817643.aspx#authaspdotnet_authentication)  on when to specify a different user for Anonymous Authentication

> If your application is using other resources, such as COM+ components,
>   databases, message queues, or UNC file shares, you will need to enable
>   the appropriate permissions for the anonymous user.